# Scenarios for asteroids 2000 QW7 and 2010 CO1 hitting the Earth?

Tags: asteroid, near-earth-asteroid, planetary-defense

These two NEOs have been appearing prominently in the popular news media recently:

- [Two Gigantic Asteroids To Zip Past Earth on September 14](https://in.mashable.com/science/6305/two-gigantic-asteroids-to-zip-past-earth-on-september-14)
- [Two Gigantic Asteroids to Fly Past Earth on 14 September](https://www.thequint.com/news/world/two-gigantic-asteroids-fly-past-earth-14-september-reports)
- [Asteroid That's Nearly the Height of the World's Tallest Building Is Flying by Earth Soon](https://www.livescience.com/asteroid-fly-by-september-2019.html)
- [NASA warns massive asteroid 2000 QW7 to skim Earth](https://www.news.com.au/technology/science/space/nasa-warns-massive-asteroid-2000-qw7-to-skim-earth/news-story/cf31b7b5454db8ed105029af40259e03)

What are the actual odds that near Earth asteroids (NEOs) 2000 QW7 ([1](http://www.minorplanet.info/PHP/GenerateALCDEFPage_Local.php?AstInfo=467317%7C2000+QW7), [2](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2000%20QW7)) and 2010 CO1 ([1](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2010%20CO1)) will hit the Earth?

If so, which areas are most susceptible?

What are the various scenarios under which these could or could not hit us?

Comment: Could you send some links to what you are referring to? Also, I think this question will be better asked in the Astronomy stack exchange.

Comment: @SCLASethKurkowski I've made a helpful edit, how does that look?

Comment: Looking forward to Independence Day 2, was a good movie, the live action version should be incredible.

Answer (score 5):

There are no scenarios for either of those asteroids hitting the earth on the next approach. Both have been tracked carefully for years, and the closest approach has been calculated at 0.035428 Astronomical units, or 3.2 million miles (5.3 million km), which is 13 times as far away as the moon orbits the earth. That is close astronomically, but it is a very comfortable distance from a safety point of view.

Comment: just curious; where did you find 0.035428 AU?

Comment: It's in the second link @uhoh.